# Cloud Foundry: Specify environment variable per application in manifest

Tags: cloud-foundry

I know I can set environment vars in a manifest as described here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block.

But, can I set them per-application?

So, something like this:

```
---
applications:
- name: app1
  env: 
    foo: bar
- name: app2
  env: 
    foo: baz
```

Comment: The format would be `foo: bar` rather than `foo=bar`, but aside from that, did you try what you described wanting to be able to do?  I imagine that should just work.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Thanks for the typo catch.  I hadn't tried it because I couldn't find it in the docs, but I'm trying it now.  Nice picture of the mountains, btw.